# How to visualize pgRouting layer in leaflet?

Tags: pgrouting, leaflet

I have completed all the queries of the of pgRouting [tutorial](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/) by [Underdark](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/187/underdark) where visualization was done with the help of RT SQL Layer Plugin. As I am using Windows OS I have no access of that tool. That is why I was unable to visualize the resultant layer of Shortest_path. If there any way to visualize this resultant layer through leaflet API it will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be useful http://gijs.github.com/blog/2012/12/16/on-using-leaflets-canvaslayer-to-interpolate-a-heightmap/

Comment: Do you need Leaflet specifically or will any solution do?

Comment: Thanks underdark for answering. If the solution can be given in Leaflet it would be more helpful to me.

Comment: I'm trying to understand if your goal is to simply see the route --> tell you how to install RT SQL Layer or similar tool for QGIS; or whether you actually need a webmapping solution --> try to find a Leaflet reference or provide link to existing OpenLayers solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Review stage:

- QGIS with PostGIS Manager and RT Sql Layer plugins

Since you're on Windows you can simply install QGIS via [OSGeo4WIn](http://osgeo4w.osgeo.org/).

Comment: I have already installed QGIS but need the RT Sql Layer Plugins.

Comment: You know how to install plugins? Go to 'plugins' 'fetch python plugins' and then make sure you add all the repositories. Search for the words you want.

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial uses QGis to display the results. This is a rich client application which contacts the database directly.

Leaflet runs in the browser and can, for instance, display GeoJSON data that it downloads from a webserver. The webserver fetches the data from the database, converts it to GeoJSON, and serves it to the browser.

If you really wish to use Leaflet to display the results, you're going to have to fill in this server tier. Depending on your OS, preferences and experience, you can take a pick from a broad range of solutions to do this.

Asp.Net, [PHP](https://gist.github.com/bmcbride/1913855), [Node.js](http://boomphisto.blogspot.nl/2011/07/nodejs-express-leaflet-postgis-awesome.html), Java servlet.